# How to obtain the hexa code of a NCHAR into a VARCHAR2

Tags: oracle, t-sql, plsql, type-conversion

I'm working on a conversion of T-SQL script into pl/sql. And i need your help about a conversion type.
My t-sql script :

```
set @cust_name_hex = convert(VARCHAR(max),convert(varbinary(max), @cust_name),2)
```

My conversion, but i'm not really sure...

```
set cust_name_hex = TO_CHAR(cust_name);
```

I've to obtain the hexa code of the 'cust_name' variable. I search on the web and every where, and i found the `WARTOHEX` function. 
I missed tu say you that the variable cust_name is a `NCHAR`. So i understand in t-sql, the schema of conversion : `NVARCHAR` -> `VARBINARY` -> `VARCHAR`.
In PL/SQL, i try to make the same conversion, but i don't obtain the good result.. I don't know how to convert a `NCHAR` in `VARCHAR2`, to give me the Hexa value...

Comment: `SELECT DUMP('text', 16) FROM dual`

Comment: The standard equivalent to SQL Server's `CONVERT()` seems to be the `CAST()` function.

Comment: Thx for tour answers, i saw the cast function too i'm gonna work on it. I can't acces to my Oracle database at this time but when i can i'm gonna execute your query lad2025. Can you explain me what the principe? I know à little the dumb table but not really good

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Combination of UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW and RAWTOHEX functions should do the job:

```
SELECT RAWTOHEX(UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW(N'unicode text')) FROM DUAL;
```

or using PL/SQL

```
DECLARE
    cust_name_hex VARCHAR2(255);
BEGIN
    cust_name_hex := RAWTOHEX(UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW(N'unicode text'));
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(cust_name_hex);
END;
```

Comment: Hi, thank's it's exactly what i'm looking for. But just a detail, i can write this ? : cust_name_hex := RAWTOHEX(UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW(cust_name)); Because i put a NCHAR into the CAST_TO_RAW, and i took a varchar2... Is it not a matter ?

Comment: N'value' means NCHAR/NVARCHAR2, I tested the CAST_TO_RAW and it produces correct bytes, for NCHAR/NVARCHAR2 two per character.